# How to put string in array, split by new line in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a following string, with line breaks in a textfile:

```
0100000184998 1 2500855884500 /RAM PRADHAN 1302 Cold
0100000186936 1 2515407774500 /HARI SHRESTHA 1302 Cold
0100000238562 1 2500211214500 /SARAL SHARMA  1301 Cold
0100000270755 0 1820823730100 /EXPRESS ACCOUNT  9999 Cold
0100000272629 0 1820833290100 /LIZA MAHARJAN 1208 Cold
0100000272637 0 2510171014500 /MAYA SHRESTHA  1208 Cold
0100000272645 0 1800505550100 /DR RIMA BHATTA  1208 Cold
0100000272652 0 1820834930100 /KAMAL BALAMI 1208 Cold
0100000272678 0 1810024300100 /VINOD BHAKTA POKHAREL  1208 Cold
```

I want to put that string in an array, and for every new line, jump one index place in the array. And then, store data into database tables.
So, the array would be like this

```
array[0][0] = "0100000184998"
array[0][1] = "1"
array[0][2] = "2500855884500"

array[1][0] = "0100000186936"
array[1][1] = "1"
array[1][3] = "RAM PRADHAN"
```

I completed selecting a file and reading the text from the file part.

```
        for (int i = 1; i < contents.Length; i++)
        {
           // string[] rowData = sourceData[i].Split(' ');
            string[] words = contents.Split(' ');
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
              Console.WriteLine(word);
            }

        }
```

Here, `Console.WriteLine(word);` contains separate separate words that is what I wanted. but, I am stuck on how to convert into multidimensional array and pass it to database table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good 'ol fashioned LINQ works:

```
@"0100000184998 1 2500855884500 /NITA PRADHAN 1302 Cold
0100000186936 1 2515407774500 /SARAL SHRESTHA 1302 Cold
0100000238562 1 2500211214500 /RASHMI SHARMA  1301 Cold
0100000270755 0 1820823730100 /EXPRESS ACCOUNT  9999 Cold
0100000272629 0 1820833290100 /SUNIL MAHARJAN 1208 Cold
0100000272637 0 2510171014500 /AJANTA SHRESTHA  1208 Cold
0100000272645 0 1800505550100 /DR BINOD BHATTA  1208 Cold
0100000272652 0 1820834930100 /PALAN BALAMI 1208 Cold
0100000272678 0 1810024300100 /BHANU BHAKTA POKHAREL  1208 Cold"
.Split(new char[]{ '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select (x => {
    string[] parts = x.Split(new char[]{ ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return parts.Take(3)
        .Union(new[]{ String.Join(" ", parts.Skip(3).Take(parts.Length - 3 - 2)) })
        .Union(parts.Skip(parts.Length - 2)).ToArray();
}).ToArray();
```

That will grab the first 3 elements & the last 2 elements, then take whatever is in the middle and create another element. outcome (first 4 results

```
result[0][0] = '0100000184998'
result[0][1] = '1'
result[0][2] = '2500855884500'
result[0][3] = '/NITA PRADHAN'
result[0][4] = '1302'
result[0][5] = 'Cold'
result[1][0] = '0100000186936'
result[1][1] = '1'
result[1][2] = '2515407774500'
result[1][3] = '/SARAL SHRESTHA'
result[1][4] = '1302'
result[1][5] = 'Cold'
result[2][0] = '0100000238562'
result[2][1] = '1'
result[2][2] = '2500211214500'
result[2][3] = '/RASHMI SHARMA'
result[2][4] = '1301'
result[2][5] = 'Cold'
result[3][0] = '0100000270755'
result[3][1] = '0'
result[3][2] = '1820823730100'
result[3][3] = '/EXPRESS ACCOUNT'
result[3][4] = '9999'
result[3][5] = 'Cold'
result[4][0] = '0100000272629'
result[4][1] = '0'
result[4][2] = '1820833290100'
result[4][3] = '/SUNIL MAHARJAN'
result[4][4] = '1208'
result[4][5] = 'Cold'
result[5][0] = '0100000272637'
result[5][1] = '0'
result[5][2] = '2510171014500'
result[5][3] = '/AJANTA SHRESTHA'
result[5][4] = '1208'
result[5][5] = 'Cold'
result[6][0] = '0100000272645'
result[6][1] = '0'
result[6][2] = '1800505550100'
result[6][3] = '/DR BINOD BHATTA'
result[6][4] = '1208'
result[6][5] = 'Cold'
result[7][0] = '0100000272652'
result[7][1] = '0'
result[7][2] = '1820834930100'
result[7][3] = '/PALAN BALAMI'
result[7][4] = '1208'
result[7][5] = 'Cold'
result[8][0] = '0100000272678'
result[8][1] = '0'
result[8][2] = '1810024300100'
result[8][3] = '/BHANU BHAKTA POKHAREL'
result[8][4] = '1208'
result[8][5] = 'Cold'
```

Comment: works great.. But `/VINOD BHAKTA POKHAREL` must be single instead of `/VINOD`,  `BHAKTA` and `POKHAREL` separate

Comment: Then the second spilt needs to be adjusted. I saw you were only splitting by a space and did the same. You can use take(3) then join the rest and make 4 tokens.

Comment: so, first 3 and last 2 columns are fixed and rest one is `customer name` , how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below !!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;


List<string[]> some_function (string fn) {    //fn = "path/to/file"
    string line;
    List<string[]> rval = new List<string[]>();
    if (File.Exists(fn)) {
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fn);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
            string[] value = line.Split(' ');
            rval.Add(value);
        }
        file.Close();
    }
    return rval;
}
```